# iOS app freezes when using Instruments Allocation

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, instruments, allocation

When I want to use Instruments Allocation to analysis the memory usage of my app, it freezes immediately after launch. And it always stuck at launchscreen(It's a Xamarin.forms app).

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Other information**:

If I create a new project and then use Instruments Allocation, it works only if I release my app to the device.(While it still can't work even if I release my app to the device)

The demo [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/profiling-memorydemo/) works too.

Any help?

update：

I found the app is crashed when launching by allocation:

```
=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:get_name <0x00007>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo:get_Name <0x00027>
      at ObjCMethod:get_IsPropertyAccessor <0x00057>
      at Registrar.Registrar:GetBindAsAttribute <0x0018f>
at ObjCMethod:get_NativeParameters <0x00067>
      at Registrar.Registrar:ComputeSignature <0x0014b>
      at ObjCMethod:ComputeSignature <0x0004f>
      at ObjCMethod:ValidateSignature <0x0004f>
      at ObjCType:Add <0x000e3>
      at Registrar.Registrar:RegisterTypeUnsafe <0x03623>
      at Registrar.Registrar:RegisterType <0x000af>
      at Registrar.DynamicRegistrar:Lookup <0x000df>
      at ObjCRuntime.Class:LookupClass <0x000b7>
      at ObjCRuntime.Class:Lookup <0x00017>
      at ObjCRuntime.Runtime:GetNSObject <0x00083>
      at UIKit.UIColor:get_Black <0x00037>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ColorExtensions:.cctor <0x00053>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x0010f>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Forms:Init <0x000c7>
      at Xamarin.iOS.AppDelegate:FinishedLaunching <0x001a3>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x0010f>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00007>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x0002f>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00043>
      at XamarinUI.iOS.Application:Main <0x0007f>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x0010f>
=================================================================
<End of Run>
```

Comment: Hi, from the shared sample, it works in my device(iPhone). Do you have a try with a iPhone device to check?